# Tasker, flash text not show up

Tags: tasker

This should be simple but no.

I try using unlock screen task and it works perfectly.

But Flash text is not show up, after screen is opened. Why?

If me test this task for play button flash text working norma

[pic of my task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgpZz.jpg)

Expecting flash text notification after screen opening